# Physics.Raycast not working with Google Cardboard / Google VR

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, raycasting, google-vr

I have a Physics Raycaster attached to the Camera. The Pointer Click Event Trigger is working correctly. However I need to do it from the source code. These are my attempts:

```
private void SetOnPushButtonFireManager(){
    cardboard.OnTrigger += () => {
        Debug.Log("Button triggered!");
        RaycastHit hit;
        // if(Physics.Raycast(headGameObject.GetComponent<GvrHead>().Gaze, out hit, Mathf.Infinity)){
        if(Physics.Raycast(cameraGameObject.transform.position, cameraGameObject.transform.forward, out hit, Mathf.Infinity)){
              Debug.Log("Collision detected!");
        }
    };
}
```

"Button triggered!" is shown in the Console. Unfortunately "Collision detected!" is not. However the Pointer Click Event Trigger is working correctly (the component attached in the inspector). How can I know what is going on? Why isn't it working?

**UPDATE: I have answered this answer here: http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/1200449/view.html**

(stackoverflow does not allow me to delete this question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code I've been using to fire a ray from the camera. I don't have Google Cardboard, this was setup for a camera and a mouse pointer.

```
   // Fire ray from camera
    float rayLength = 2f
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit hit;

    // If ray hits object within length
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, rayLength))
    {
            Debug.Log("Collision detected!:);
    }
```

Comment: I want to fire a ray from the center of the camera when the player pushes the button. So I have modified your code to `Ray ray = Camera.main.ViewportPointToRay (new Vector3(0.5f,0.5f,0f));` Unfortunately that does not work. Thank you for your help anyway! :)

Comment: I have answered this question here: http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/1200449/view.html I close this question.

Answer (score 0):

It didn't work for me either, in the end, I forgot to put the "GvrPointerPhysicsRaycaster" class in the camera. [Inspector Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVSRJ.png)

Once added, it worked perfectly.

```
void Update()
{
    RaycastHit hit;

    if (Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.transform.position, Camera.main.transform.forward, out hit, Mathf.Infinity))
    {
        if (activeSelected == null)
        {
            if (hit.collider.tag == "Plane")
                activeSelected = Instantiate(mainApp.mainModel.preafabSelect, hit.point, Quaternion.LookRotation(hit.normal));
        } else
        {
            activeSelected.transform.position = hit.point;
            activeSelected.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(hit.normal);
        }
    }
}
```